# Minesweeper like boards generating in Haskell - ideas

Tags: haskell

First of all I want to describe a problem (it's very similar to Minesweeper). We've given an *n* × *m* board and a list of special points (*x*,*y*,*z*). Each point says that around field (*x*,*y*) we need to place exactly *z* mines.

You can find also better discription of problem here : [Prolog: where to begin solving Minesweeper-like puzzel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983206/prolog-where-to-begin-solving-minesweeper-like-puzzel)
(it's in prolog but don't care about programming language)

Our task is to generate all possible boards that satisfies task conditions.
For example:
Let `n = 3`, `m = 3` and `L = [(2,2,1)]` is a list of special points, so possible solution is:

```
[[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', 1, ' '], [' ', ' ', *]]
```

where ' ' is blank space and '*' is mine.

I want to find some usefull ideas to write this problem in Haskell. My only idea is to generate all possible combinations of setting mines or use backtracking but i found it very hard to implement in haskell.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backtracking is super easy in Haskell using the list monad.  Here's an example:

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

pairs :: [(Int,Int)]
pairs = do
    x <- [1..10]
    y <- [1..x]
    guard (even (x + y))
    return (x,y)
```

Will give you all pairs `(x,y)` such that `y <= x` and `x + y` is even.

So you will want something like

```
type Board = ...

insertMine :: (Int,Int) -> Board -> [Board]
-- return all ways of inserting a mine adjacent to the given coordinate

insertMines :: (Int,Int) -> Board -> [Board]
insertMines p board = do
    b1 <- insertMine p board
    b2 <- insertMine p b1
    b3 <- insertMine p b2
    return b3
```

There are lots of ways to make this simpler and more abstract, but I'm trying to give an example near what I perceive to be your level.  Backtracking via the list monad is a great way to get comfortable with monads, too!

Comment: What means "guard" in your code? Is it possible to edit list in resonable time?

Comment: What do you mean by edit?   As for guard... play with the example and see if you can figure it out. ;)